# How to align all elements in the tr to the left side of the table?

Tags: css

I have a table with couple inputs and button on the last row. I want to align them all to the left side. Is it possible to apply float:left to all tr ? also I want it work for IE :)

I have:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <th> </th>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply text-align to your desired cells..

To do all cells do this:

```
td, th {text-align:left}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work?

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:left">html here</td>
</tr>
```

That should align all elements to the left.  If the table looks funny, make sure you don't need to use `colspan`.

Comment: I want to move all tr to left, because I have multiple elements inside. Updated question

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can apply it to the entire row. `text-align:left` would do the trick I think.

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr style="float:left">
   <th> </th>
   <td> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```